# Using setAttributes() returns a fatal error

Tags: media

I have the following code in a rule:

```
$imgpath = file_load(($node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']))->uri;
$image = theme('image_style', array('path' => $imgpath, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail'));

$link = l($image, "node/$node->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
print $link;
```

I need to add a class to the thumbnail picture. I change the code as follows, but I get a fatal error about calling a member function on a non-object.

```
$imgpath = file_load(($node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']))->uri;
$image = theme('image_style', array('path' => $imgpath, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail'));
$image->setAttribute("class", "AnyClass");

$link = l($image, "node/$node->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
print $link;
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error is simply caused from the fact you are trying to access a member function for something that is an object; in fact, [`theme_image_style()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!image!image.module/function/theme_image_style/7) is returning a string, not an object. This is true also for Drupal 8.

> Returns HTML for an image using a specific image style.

To set attributes, just use the following code.

```
$imgpath = file_load(($node->field_image[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['fid']))->uri;
$image = theme('image_style', array('path' => $imgpath, 'style_name' => 'thumbnail', 'attributes' => array('class' => array('AnyClass'))));

$link = l($image, "node/$node->nid", array('html' => TRUE));
print $link;
```

It works because `theme_image_style()`, as `theme_image()`, accepts a list of attributes to add to the image tag.

Comment: I understand, thank you.  What should I replace the setAttribute() with then? (I am very new at php and i am still far from understanding all its intricacies and subtleties.)

Comment: See the updated answer.

Comment: Yes, I understand the logic now. It works very well. Thanks a million for the lesson. :) (You may want to edit the answer and add back the print $link statement so as not to confuse anyone else.)